# Converting time to fraction of days in python

Tags: python

How do I convert date and time into fraction of days format ?

To be clearer, I have date and time like "26 days,0:16:53". Is there any way to convert this into one number that would be the equivalent value of the above in the format of days only ( fraction value). Example 26.XXXX where 'XXXX' is the fraction of a day corresponding to "0:16:53" in the above example. Is there any way to do this ?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you need to parse the date or do you have that already covered?

Comment: Do you have an actual string or a `timedelta` object? As that looks suspiciously like the `str` of that object :)

Comment: It is a timedelta object. Not a string

Comment: It is actually the difference between two dates

Comment: I know what it is thanks :) I was pointing out that you're implying you have a string containing a "date"... nowhere do you mention you already have a `timedelta` object...

Comment: Ok i m sorry if my post didnt mean wt i wanted to convey

Comment: @JonClements is right. Your question is somewhat misleading when you say: _I have date and time like "26 days,0:16:53"_. For example, my first comment was if you needed to parse that string. For further question it is important to narrow down the problem to the minimum and explain it well :)

Comment: yea i get it. I m sorry

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Well, it should be something like this:

```
dt = timedelta(days=26, hours=0, minutes=16, seconds=53)
secs_per_day = 24*60*60    # hours * mins * secs
dt.total_seconds()/secs_per_day
>>>26.011724537037036
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: :) It is the only way it occurs to me.

Comment: As an alternative to `secs_per_day` you could use `timedelta(days=1).total_seconds()`